# React use ref to scroll to a specific component when click on link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, react-forwardref

I would like to know how to use React `refs` to navigate to a specific component

```
 function App() {
      const CompetencesRef = React.useRef();
      const ExperiencesRef = React.useRef();
      const FormationRef = React.useRef();
      const RecoRef = React.useRef();
    
    
      return (
        <ParallaxProvider>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <div className="App">
    
              <div className="hero">
                <HeaderApp />
                <ApprochApp />
              </div>
              <Apropos />
              <Competences parentRef={CompetencesRef} />
              <Experiences parentRef={ExperiencesRef} />
              <Formation parentRef={FormationRef} />
              <Recom parentRef={RecoRef} />
              <Contact />
              <Footer />
    
            </div >
          </ThemeProvider>
        </ParallaxProvider>
      );
    }
```

**AppHeader**

```
 const AppHeader = () => {
        return (
            <div >
                <Headroom>
                    <MenuApp />
                </Headroom>
    
            </div>
        )
}


   export default AppHeader
```

**AppMenu**

```
   const MenuApp = () => {
        return (
            <div className="menu sticky-inner grid-container">
                <div className="desktop-menu">
                    <div className="menu-item a-propos">
                        <p className='button'>Me découvrir</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="menu-item competences">
                        <p className='button'>Compétences </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="menu-item experiences">
                        <p className='button'>Experiences</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="menu-item formation">
                        <p className='button'>Formation </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p className="mobile-menu">
                    <MenuIcon />
                </p>
                <div className="github-ico">
                    <GitHubIcon />
                </div>
                <div className="linkedin-ico">
                    <LinkedInIcon />
                </div>
                <div className="contact">
                    <div className='contact-btn'>
                        <span className="contact-ico"> <MessageIcon /></span>  <span style={isBrowser ? { display: 'block' } : { display: 'none' }} > contact </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default MenuApp
```

I have understood that I should declare ref on the parent component, but I'm stuck on how to pass references to the menu app and make the link between it and components.

Actually, I would not use packages like [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [forwarding-refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

in the parent

```
const RecoRef = React.useRef();
....
<ChildComponent ref={RecoRef} />
```

in the child component

```
//export the component with React.forwardRefs

const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
        .....
        </div>
    )
}

export default React.forwardRefs(ChildComponent)
```

Comment: Your example does not include the click event

Comment: Pass a click handler to the child component from parent, and when click happens inside child component it will call the click handler inside parent, based on the clicked item scroll to the ref

Answer (score 0):

Two things are needed: a `ref` and [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).
this snippent is simplified version of sharing a ref between component, there is `redDiv` and a `button` in the header that scrolls into that div; I'd created the ref in the top parent element, then passed it as props to both header and the component I wanted to scroll into; in the header there is a button that calls `scrollIntoView` method on that `ref` and thus browser will scroll that element into view;

```js
const AppHeader = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="menu sticky-inner grid-container">
            my logo
            <button onClick={()=> props.iconMenuRefs[0].current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})}
            > scroll to red div </button>
            <button onClick={()=> props.iconMenuRefs[1].current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})}
            > scroll to blue div </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
  const redDivRef = React.useRef();
  const blueDivRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <AppHeader iconMenuRefs={[redDivRef, blueDivRef]}/>
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <SimpleComp ref={redDivRef} color="red"/>
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <SimpleComp ref={blueDivRef} color="blue"/>
    </div>
  );
}

const SimpleComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div style={{backgroundColor: props.color}} ref={ref}>scroll to me!</div>
})

ReactDOM.render( <App />, myApp )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```